# Dynamically decrease the height of dialog with WebView as HTML content changes, .... or fix height

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a DialogFragment (displayed as a dialog) whose layout contains a WebView control.
The layout is setup to `wrap_content`. I'm working on a tablet and do want to display as a dialog but do not want to have the height match that of the screen.

The web view displays HTML content which is defined at build time.

The HTML contains links which can hide and show content (hiding/showing 'divs').

As I click on links to expand them then the height of the dialog increases as content is shown.

However, when I collapse entries the height of the dialog does not contract.

My preference would be to fix the height of the dialog after the content has loaded. Failing that to have the height of the dialog decrease as content is hidden.

Thanks in advance, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the code needs cleaning up and there may be neater ways of doing it but I put the following in the `onPageFinished` event for the WebView and it does the job for me of fixing the dialog height after the html content has been loaded.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    ....
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (webView.getHeight() < currentHeight) {
          currentHeight = webView.getHeight();
        }
        final LayoutParams params = webView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = currentHeight;
        webView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Simple Try***

Try to `invalidate();` in the onClickListener

```
yourWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TRY to invalidate();

        // Try to setVisibility(View.GONE); then directly (View.VISIBLE)      
        return false;
    } 
});
```

---

***Harder Stuff***

- Navigate through the source code of the WebView
- Follow the execution of the clicks (I beleive you should start from `loadUrl()`)
- Try to reach to the point which is causing the WebView to become larger when a div is shown

There, you might find a way to imitate this behavior when the div is gone

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although this didn't solve my problem I think that it has the potential to with a bit more thought on my part, perhaps invalidating the right thing (I have a FrameLayout within a LinearLayout) or as you suggest digging down deeper. It did get me thinking though about things I can be doing on touch events and from this managed to fix the height of the dialog by setting the WebView height to the minimum of what it's ever been. This seems to work for me and fixes the height of the dialog (there may be other ways but I'll post as an answer my solution).

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be possible, I believe having a dialog that changes size as the user interacts with it is not a very good user interface (I don't know your application so perhaps I might be misjudging). Perhaps you should consider a regular Activity instead of displaying your Webview in a dialog box.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm constrained by customer requirements, and the nature of the app on the tablet, to have it displayed as a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I come from an iOS background. You need to use something similar to a popover control in iPad.

Alternatively you can use LayoutInflator to adjust the size of the view. [This blog post (Layou resources in Android)](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/26/layout-resources-in-android/) seems to describe exactly how to do this. Looks like people have had good results with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using a DialogFragment and inflating the view in `onCreateView`. In my layout I've set `wrap_content` so either looking for a way of then fixing the view after the web page has finished loading (my preference) or determining when the drop downs in the web page have been collapsed and then resizing the dialog, code samples would be useful.